# How to find the joomla page from url

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, articles

Client provide me the url of the joomla page. But I am not able to find it from the administrator. I check every article but I am not able to find it.

Can anybody please help me with it where I can find it

The url is something like this

**example.com/index.php/resource-downloads**

I have url but I am not able to find this page in administrator.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can find any url/Alias by searching it in the **search box**.

First go to the Menu manager and enter **resource-downloads** in the search box.

And if you didnt find it then you can go to the article manager and type the alias of the article in the search box.

Eg : search for **resource-downloads** in the search box and you will find the article or menu item by this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a single article menu item.

Go to the Menu Manager look through each menu group for a menu item with "resource-downloads" as the alias (most likely the title of the menu item will be "Resource Downloads" but that's not a guarantee because the menu title and alias don't need to be similar).

[image]

Once you find the menu item enter/edit it and look at the "Select Article" field; that's the article being loaded. Click "Edit" and it'll bring you to the article that menu item displays.

[image]